Where to get historical database of Twitter followers / following
Is there a service that has been collecting Twitter followers / friends (ie follows) data for years, and makes it available as an API or download?
The Twitter API has recently (2023) shut off access to this data but we are looking for historical data (friends/list rarely changes for most celebrities) for data science purposes. So we can analyze statistics on users, and test hypotheses, for instance.
I did not see anything in the Twitter terms of service from before, about not allowing storing of Twitter metadata, so I think using that historical data from before 2023 (if it is somewhere) is not violating their terms of service.
Anyone know any existing services that have done this? Please share a link where to get the data (database is preferred but an API is fine too.
